# how to sort the following php array?

Tags: php, arrays

Question

```
Array ( [0] => 12w12 [1] => 13w12 [2] => 14w12 [3] => 15w12 [4] => 2w13 [5] => 3w13 [6] => 4w13 [7] => 3w12 [8] => 7w12 [9] => 9w12 )
```

Answer should be

```
Array ( [0] => 3w12 [1] => 7w12 [2] => 9w12 [3] => 12w12 [4] => 13w12 [5] => 14w12 [6] => 15w12 [7] => 2w13 [8] => 3w13 [9] =>4w13  )
```

Comment: What is 2w13 and how come it comes __after__ 15w12?

Comment: ordered by second "field" first ?

Comment: hint: you just have to write a comparison function

Comment: 2w13 is 2nd week of 2013 and 15w12 is 15th week of 2012 that's why is comes after 15w12

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PHP usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and write your own comparison function.

Answer (score 1):

```
function cmp($a, $b){
    if ($a == $b) { return 0; }

    list($first1, $last1) = explode("w", $a);
    list($first2, $last2) = explode("w", $b);

    return (($last1.$first1) < ($last2.$first2)) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($array, "cmp");
```

Answer (score -1):

do a bit search on php.net for usort and make your own sorting method as what you are trying to achieve don't seem standard ordering at all